# Получить новое значение getLeft() при повороте экрана

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста, как получить значение скажем кнопки getLeft() при повороте экрана, если активити новое не пересоздается?
У меня в манифесте:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

И проблема в том, что мне после поворота экрана надо получить новое значение кнопки button.getLeft(), а она показывает предыдущее, то есть если мы с горизонтального положения перевернем в вертикальное, то getLeft() показывает значение еще горизонтального положения, и наоборот..

Получаю так:

```
//отследить поворот экрана
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    int btn_left = button.getLeft();
}
```

Comment: `Внимание! Начиная с Android 3.2 (уровень API 13), «размер экрана» также изменяется при переходе между книжной и альбомной ориентациями устройства. Таким образом, если в режиме выполнения требуется предотвратить перезапуск вследствие изменения ориентации при разработке для уровня API 13 или выше (как объявлено в атрибутах minSdkVersion и targetSdkVersion ), необходимо включить значение "screenSize" в дополнение к значению "orientation". То есть необходимо объявить android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize".` https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes?hl=ru

Comment: Грубо говоря, если использовать `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` данный чит, то вы действительно перевернете экран, но перезапуска активности не будет, а следовательно данный триггер не сработает, и вследствие данные не обновятся, что собственно у вас и происходит.

Comment: iFr0z, спс, ну а какой выход-то, как узнать новое положение getLeft() при повороте экрана в моем случае? Перезапуска активити быть не должно(манифест не трогаем), поэтому нужны другие методы или хитрости..

Comment: "Перезапуска активити быть не должно" - Жестко как-то, а почему такое ограничение? и из-за чего? если не секрет.

Comment: Да уже так сделан весь проект. Чтобы при поворотах никаких перерасчетов и казусов нигде не происходило. Так-то все нормально, вопрос только в этом, каким способом отследить положение view. Не верится, что нет способов.